# Issues with rewrite-target for iis site on kubernetes pod

Tags: nginx, iis, kubernetes, azure-aks

We have several `namespaces`, each of which contain an instance of our product running on  `IIS`  on a windows pod. We do not want to expose this pods to the internet and as such are looking to enable a bastion `VM` on the same `vnet` to access them through an `NGINX` ingress controller.

This ingress controller is setup and working but we are running into some issues. Our goal is to be able to route between instances of the application based on a path e.g. `nginxIP`/instance1 routing to 1 instance and `nginxIP`/instance2 routing to a second.

The following is a sample ingress `yaml file` which we are using in the solution currently:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: instance1-ingress
  namespace: instance1
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /instance1(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: service
          servicePort: 80
```

This is redirecting to the root of the application successfully however there are lots of issues with the application loading `css`, images and other scripts. It seems that this is not being handled properly by the rewrite rule but after trying several different configurations of paths, rewrite targets as well as testing the app-root annotation I am at a loss.

The other thing of note here is that different `behaviour` can be observed depending on whether a trailing slash is used or not. For example this image on the homepage works fine when you use a slash but not without:

http://10.240.10.10/instance1/

works - http://10.240.10.10/instance1/b3c7ad64-a4e1-4c32-a616-6153ff535a83.adapter

http://10.240.10.10/instance1

doesn't work - http://10.240.10.10/b3c7ad64-a4e1-4c32-a616-6153ff535a83.adapter

Which I'm hoping offers some clues to what might be the issue here but after quite a while looking into this I'm now at a bit of a loss

Comment: If I understand well, do you whant redirect `http://my_ip/instance1` to `http://my_ip/` but in the instance1 app, the same for `instance2`...etc. I mean, do you want to redirect to the correct instance, but you want to omit the `instance1` from url, right?

Answer (score 0):

you are saying this doesn't work - http://10.240.10.10/b3c7ad64-a4e1-4c32-a616-6153ff535a83.adapter because you are missing /instance1/ in the URL.
The rewrite target does not rewrite the URL so you will need to this path: /instance1/

You will need to update the frontend code for this serverside routing to work.